# Using SQL Query to insert data in Oracle DB and Generating Unique ID

Tags: sql, database, oracle

Scenario: For order Booking, I enter the required details in the oracle R12 forms and when I click on the save button, the system generates Order ID. I access oracle DB and find the furnished info and the Order ID under a specific table.

Question: If I use SQL Query to insert the required data directly into Oracle DB using Insert query instead of the UI form, will the application or DB still generate the Order ID and populate the Order ID field under a specific table?.

Note: I have limited technical knowledge. Looking for a functional solution.

Thanks in Advance, Cheers.

Comment: You need to find out *how* the order ID is currently being generated. It may be a sequence with the column populated by a trigger, or an auto-increment column; or the application may be generating it some other way. Without knowing what is happening now it's impossible to say.

Comment: If you have access to the data dictionary, you might be able to find out if the ID is added by a trigger.  The following query 'should' tell you if there is a trigger on your table and that bit of info would be help us help you: SELECT * FROM all_triggers WHERE table_name = '[Your Table Name]';.

Comment: if you can get some time with your dba, he/she could turn on tracing on the form.  After tracing is on, you need to go through the steps of inserting a row, the sql will be logged to the trace file and the dba can extract the sqls for you

Comment: more importantly -- are you trying to insert into an oracle R12 table or a custom table?  you should never insert directly into an oracle R12 table, you should contact oracle support and they can give you a script, otherwise you can corrupt your data

Comment: Hello All, thank you for your suggestions. Is there a general approach or sure-shot method to identify how the ID is getting generated. I can take it up with my technical counterpart and check it out.